# Bootstrap navbar dropdown, keeping it to the right at low resolutions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with my dropdown inside of my bootstrap navbar.  I would like the drop down arrow to stick to the right of the navbar and stay on the same line as the brand image when moved to lower resolutions.  Also, when clicked i'd like the dropdown background color to be white.  Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the code:

http://www.bootply.com/d1kFiYXPox

Answer (score 0):

To keep the arrow on the same line remove the margins that you've set for small screens. So remove "margin: 50px auto 0 120px;" from the line below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
    width: 110px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 120px;
}
```

On your example the background of dropdown is white already.